# Are the rules fired in easy rules not exclusive based on priority?

Tags: java, rule-engine

I am trying to work with EasyRules.

I have created 3 rules A, B & C with priorities 1, 2 & 3 respectively.

Even though **rule A** is evaluated to **true** and has the highest priority, rules with lower priority (i.e. B & C) are being evaluated.

How does this rule priority work?

Is there a work around where if a rule with higher priority is evaluated to true, then rules with lower priority are not evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority has no relation with whether a rule is executed or not. It indicates only the execution order of the rules

From the documentation :

> Each rule in Easy Rules has a priority. This represents the default
> order in which registered rules are fired. By default, lower values
> represent higher priorities.

You can also read :

> A composite rule is triggered if all conditions of its composing rules
> are satisfied. When a composite rule is applied, actions of all
> composing rules are performed in the natural order of rules which is
> rules priorities by default.

If you want the engine to skip rules after a rule is applied, you should provide the engine with the param `skipOnFirstAppliedRule` set to `true`.

```
RulesEngine  rulesEngine = RulesEngineBuilder.aNewRulesEngine()
                          .withSkipOnFirstAppliedRule(true)
                          .build();

// add your rules in the RulesEngine
rulesEngine.registerRule(new A());
rulesEngine.registerRule(new B());
rulesEngine.registerRule(new C());

// execute the rules
rulesEngine.fireRules();
```

In your case, only the `A` rule will be executed.

Comment: Thanks. This cleared a lot of things. So that means, i'll have to use a combination of priority and `.withSkipOnFirstAppliedRule(true)` to achieve the desired behavior.